# Override show(_:sender:) of UIViewController freezes the UI

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I can't override the `show(_:sender:)` method of UIViewController or else my app freezes when the method is called (Xcode 15.3 simulator, iOS 17.4, macOS Sonoma 14.3.1, MacBook Air M1 8GB).

Here is a table view that helps illustrate the UI freeze when you tap the right bar button item, which calls an overridden `show(_:sender:)` method:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableView = UITableView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = .init(title: "Present", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentViewController))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = .init(title: "Show", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(showViewController))
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    @objc func presentViewController() {
        present(AnotherViewController(), animated: true)
    }

    override func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        super.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: flag, completion: completion)
        
    }
    
    @objc func showViewController() {
        show(AnotherViewController(), sender: self)
    }
    
    override func show(_ vc: UIViewController, sender: Any?) {
        super.show(vc, sender: sender)
        
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        var contentConfiguration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
        contentConfiguration.text = "Cell"
        cell.contentConfiguration = contentConfiguration
        return cell
    }
}

class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    }
}
```

As you can see, you may call an overridden `present(_:animated:completion)` (by tapping the left bar button item), but you may not call an overridden `show(_:sender:)`.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`UIViewController show(_:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621377-show):

> The default implementation of this method calls the `targetViewController(forAction:sender:)` method to locate an object in the view controller hierarchy that overrides this method. It then calls the method on that target object, which displays the view controller in an appropriate way. If the `targetViewController(forAction:sender:)` method returns nil, this method uses the window’s root view controller to present vc modally.

The problem with your code is that `targetViewController(forAction:sender:)` is returning `self` since it is `ViewController` that is overriding `show(_:sender:)`. So you end up in an infinite recursive loop of calls to `show(_:sender:)`. You can see this if you put a breakpoint in your overridden `show(_:sender:)` and let the breakpoint be hit a couple of times. You can also add:

```swift
override func targetViewController(forAction action: Selector, sender: Any?) -> UIViewController? {
    let res = super.targetViewController(forAction: action, sender: sender)
    print(res === self)
    return res
}
```

and you will see "true" printed over and over.

When you override `show(_:sender:)` you should actually perform the logic to show the given view controller instead of calling `super.show(vc, sender: sender)`.

Overriding `present` to call `super.present` doesn't have the same problem because the logic of the default implementation of `present` doesn't use `targetViewController(forAction:sender:)` to find the implementor of `present` like `show` does.

You should only override `show(_:sender:)` in a custom container view controller class that needs to display the requested view controller is some specific way not handled by the normal framework.

Comment: (1/2) that’s a shame. View controllers in my app inherit from a custom view controller, and I wanted to store the view controller that calls `show(_:sender:)` (the sender parameter for how I use the method) in a “showingViewController” property, in the shown view controller, to allow it in viewWillDisappear to ask the showingViewController to deselect the deselected cells, assuming the showing view controller has a collection view or a table view. But now I’m not sure how to reference the vc that initiates the show request from the shown vc since I can’t super `show(_:sender:)`.

Comment: (2/2) Unfortunately, KVO, with any combination of options, doesn’t seem to catch up on framework properties like presentingViewController or isBeingPresented, which is why I wanted to deselect the cells of the showing vc in the viewWillDisappear of the shown vc, even though it’s not ideal since viewWillDisappear isn’t only called when the vc is dismissed, in the first place. So, at this point, I can’t think of anything that I can do at the parent class level. Do you think I could ask for advice in a dedicated stackoverflow question?

Comment: It sounds like you have no need to override `show(_:sender:)`. It sounds like you should be using some sort of delegate pattern. Also keep in mind that there are already ways for a presenting view controller to know when the presented view controller is being or has been dismissed. Existing questions already cover that topic. If you are still stuck, post a new question focused on your actual goal and where you are having issues.

Comment: I see. Could you please give a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78248735/cant-display-the-simplest-uitoolbar