# Can't display the simplest UIToolbar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, constraints, uitoolbar

I thought I could easily display a toolbar in UIKit, but I was wrong, or at least I can't do so without getting "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints." console messages.

Here is my code:

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        toolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        ]
        view.addSubview(toolbar)
        toolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            toolbar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
            toolbar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            toolbar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            toolbar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
        ])
    }
}
```

And here is the console log:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002107b10 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002122e90 V:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002121ef0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0.bottom == _UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002107a70 UIButtonLabel:0x10250f280.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210ea30 'TB_Baseline_Baseline' _UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title'.lastBaseline == UILayoutGuide:0x600003b0ca80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210ea80 'TB_Top_Top' V:|-(>=0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210e8f0 'UIButtonBar.maximumAlignmentSize' _UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120.height == UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.height   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000212c960 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210ec60 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b0ca80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(11)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000212d6d0 'UIView-topMargin-guide-constraint' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0 )>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002107a70 UIButtonLabel:0x10250f280.centerY == _UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title'.centerY + 1.5   (active)>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x600002106710 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002120b40 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002122e40 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x104008e40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210eda0 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(16)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210eb70 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210e580 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210e5d0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == UIView:0x10400e480.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210e9e0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120]-(0)-[UIView:0x10400e480]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000212c820 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000212ca00 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x600003b00380'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10250d8b0 )>"
)
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000210eb70 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1027059c0'Title']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x102607120 )>
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I tried giving the toolbar a frame rather than constraints, and also to not give it an explicit height.

The only thing that works is to comment out `UIBarButtonItem(title: "Title", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)`, which isn't really a solution.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `let toolbar = UIToolbar()` to `let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50` and see if the warning goes away. This should make no difference to your code otherwise, because the constraints will take over when you turn off `translates` and apply the constraints instead.

Comment: This seems like a bug in iOS but matt's solution of giving the toolbar an initial frame (even though it shouldn't be needed) does resolve the constraint issues. You should also remove the height constraint since the toolbar will provide its own height.