Can I use Firestore locally for free?
I'm making an iOS retail app.
Currently, whenever the user makes a change to the draft order, I save it to the relative order document, to which the client is also listening, so each edit to the draft order by the user accounts for one read and one write.
Since the user is the only person that can see their draft order, it would make more sense, to save money, to edit it locally and only upload it to the remote database once in a while, like when the app enters the background and when the user pulls down to refresh the order page.
I guess I could CryptoKit or something to save the order locally in a secure manner, but I would find it easier to just use Firestore locally for free. Honestly I've never looked at CryptoKit and I've only scratched the surface with other iOS persistency technologies, so maybe plists could be considered secure enough for my use case.
In any case, can I use Firestore locally for free?
I guess not, but it would be a very useful feature.
Feel free to give me any suggestions.
Please note that I want to save the order on the device's disk for every change so that data isn't lost in case of a crash.

Your question is getting downvoted likely because you could have done some web searches to find your options. Also, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, not questions about how to find free software.

I did but it seemed too bad to be true. I was expecting to be downvoted, since even good questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241008/override-show-sender-of-uiviewcontroller-freezes-the-ui got some downvotes (which I guess then got canceled out by the upvotes), so I'm fine with them. I asked this here because last time I was answered by you and another Firebaser, and you answered this time too as I was hoping. If the question will be deleted so be it. But yes maybe I should have used other tools.

Ok I had no idea. I can't delete the question now. I'll consider other solutions in the future.

The Firestore emulator is free.  So is the Firebase emulator suite, which includes a Firestore emulator.
The Firestore cloud service has a free monthly quota.
